# Java - parse string to Json and convert all number values to int

Tags: java, json

When I parse string:

```
{"action":"duelInvite","id":"1","matchType":"3"}
```

to JsonObject in this case all values are strings, but how to create JsonObject, that maps **id** and **matchType**  to int? Do I have to do it manually, when getting those values? It's easier to `.getInt("id")` rather than `Integer.parseInt(.getString("id"))`

Comment: before parsing json, do something like this with the input: `input.replaceAll(":\\"(\\d+)\\", ":$1");`

Comment: Which `JsonObject` type? Map the content to a POJO.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a JSON Object from a string, all values become strings within the JSON Object. So you're right, you'll have to do it manually. But instead of parsing every time you want to get the values, just do it once when you create the object.

```
//create your object from the string
jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);    
//set the key "id" to the integer value of the String at key "id"
jsonObject.put("id", Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("id")));
//set the key "matchType" to the integer  value of the String at key "matchType"
jsonObject.put("matchType", Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("matchType")));
```

Comment: I can't create jsonObject like you did. It implements all abstract methods. I do it this way: `JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(message)); JsonObject jsonMessage = reader.readObject();`. Then again I cannot put straight int into jsonObject, it needs to be JsonValue